# Calculating hash of original message by encoded message

Tags: encryption, hash, block-cipher

Consider E - encryption function and H - function calculating hash of message.
Is there any E, H for which for message M:

```
H(E(M)) = H(M)
```

Comment: Do you want this to hold for all messages? If so this would probably imply E to be the identity function.

Comment: If E is *not* the identity function (and, in particular, if it's practical to find a message M such the E(M) ≠ M), then H cannot be collision resistant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SEJPM notes in the comments, this is trivially achieved by making $E$ the identity function, such that $E(M) = M$ for all $M$.

If $E$ is *not* the identity function (and, in particular, if it's practical to find a message $M$ such the $E(M) ≠ M$), then $H(E(M)) = H(M)$ would be a [collision attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) on $H$.

Normal [cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) are supposed to be collision resistant, so for such hash functions $H$ there cannot be any such function $E$ (at least, none that is practically computable and distinguishable from identity), or else the hash is broken.

---

But I suspect what you're really looking for is something else, such as $H'(E(M)) = H(M)$, where $H'$ and $H$ are two different hash functions.  This is easy to achieve by defining $H$ as $H(x) := H'(E(x))$ or, if $E$ is invertible, by defining $H'$ as $H'(x) := H(E^{-1}(x))$.  However, defining $H$ (or $H'$) like this does mean that if computing $E = E_K$ requires some secret key $K$, then the same key will also be needed to compute at least one of $H$ or $H'$.

What if we wanted to have $H'(E_K(M)) = H(M)$, where neither of $H$ and $H'$ depend on the key $K$?  In that case (assuming the $H$ isn't constant, and in particular that an attacker can choose two messages $M_0$ and $M_1$ such that $H(M_0) ≠ H(M_1)$) $E$ cannot be an [IND-CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#IND-CPA) secure encryption scheme, and thus cannot be [semantically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).  Semantic security is commonly considered the minimum baseline requirement for a secure modern encryption scheme (although there *are* some weaker but still useful security properties, such as Rogaway and Shrimpton's [DAE security](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/keywrap.html)), so by that definition, even $H'(E_K(M)) = H(M)$ isn't achievable if $E$ is supposed to be secure (and $H$ is distinguishable from a constant function).